# Does SQL CE 4 (CTP) support ambient transactions using System.Transaction namespace?

Tags: c#, sql-server-ce

From what I can see the .NET drivers for SQL CE 3.5 and below do not support System.Transactions. Has this changed for the new version of SQLCE (version 4)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, no changes there... http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896149.aspx

Comment: The link that you included only refer's to SQL CE version 3.5.  I cannot find any specific references for version 4.

Comment: There are no changes for version 4