# Entity Framework transactionscope support for sqlserver ce 4

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4

Does SQLSERVER CE 4 support transactionscope?

In this example, I am using `transactionscopeoption.suppress`, so it does not do transaction.

`createm` and `createb` is a CRUD insert new record.

Below is my code:

```
// save merchant account & bank information into database
using (var transaction = new transactionscope(transactionscopeoption.suppress))
{
    try
    {
        viewmodel.merchantdata.createm(m);
        viewmodel.bankdata.createb(b);
        transaction.complete();
    }
    catch (exception ex)
    {
        // fail to save into database
        transaction.dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: Exact duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4203358/sql-ce-4-system-transaction-support

Comment: SQL CE does not support transaction scope. here is the answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5153573/error-on-using-transactionscope-in-ef4-sql-compact-4

Comment: So How can I implement transaction for Entity Framewrok with SQL CE?